# long table in landscape two column mode

Tags: two-column, landscape, supertabular

I have a long table (>800 rows) but in order to reduce number of pages, I decided to put it in a two column mode, so that the table starts by filling the first column and continues on the second column. But some contents are too long to fit into one column and I really want to avoid line breaks, so I also decided to put it in a landscape mode. But I just can't get it to work. Also I want the headings of the table repeat when it continues from new columns. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape,geometry,multicol}


\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\begin{landscape}
\section{Past AP Free Response Questions}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'AP Index'

    \begin{supertabular}{rlll}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Year}} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Part} & \textbf{General Topics} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB1 BC1 & (a)   & differentiation \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB1 BC1 & (b)   & total change given rate of change \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB1 BC1 & (c)   & differentiation \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB1 BC1 & (d)   & maximum, minimum \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB2   & (a) (b) (c) (d) & motion on a line \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2013} & AB2   & (a) (c) (d) & differentiation \\

  ...
    \end{supertabular}%

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach suffers from a potentially serious design flaw: By using the `l` column type, there's no guarantee at all that the `supertabular` material will fit in a landscape-mode problem.

Comment: You also wrote "I want the headings of the table repeat when it continues from new columns". For that, you need to provide `\tablehead`, `\tablefirsthead`, `\tabletail`, and `\tablelasttail` directives, *before* starting the `supertabular` environment.

Comment: longtable or supertabular doesn't treat the tables as float, hence it breaks page to page by auto, but landscape should treats as float, so it won't break by auto...